# Adobe premiere CS5 problem with the display driver

Tags: windows-7, opengl, nvidia-quadro

*This error is really hindering our project.*

I get an error, it started showing-up June 16th 2010.
There are no windows updates at the on the same date as the error, other than (Windows Defender)

Seems to happen when working with Image overlays.
**ERROR:** "The NVIDIA OpenGL driver detected a problem with the display driver and is unable to continue. The application must close."

We opened the side of the case in the possibility there is an over heating problem.

[image: picture of message box]

**Nvidia Driver** 
ver 8.16.11.9175 
 (nVidia Quadro FX 1700)

**I am running:**  
Windows 7 x64 
Adobe premiere CS5 Production 
nVidia Quadro FX 1700 (MRGA14L) 
4 Gig ram 
RAID 10 2 750GB drives 
Duo core 3.0 6MB L2 Cache

**This is at least three other people that have come across this error:**

[NVidia Forum](http://developer.nvidia.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=4765&pid=14363&st=0&#entry14363)

[EVGA Forum](http://www.evga.com/forumsarchive/printable.asp?m=100876982)

[NVidia Forum](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=151152)

**UPDATE:**
Having the case open did not help.
I also installed New Nvidia drivers now I get a different error:

**ERROR:**Your hardware configuration does not meet minimum specifications needed to run the application. The application must close.

[image: picture of message box]

I ran Windows Update and installed all four updates so now I am waiting to see if the error occurs again.

Anything beyond this I am out of options.

Comment: I always felt the hardware acceleration in Photoshop CS4 performed really badly and always turned it off. In Visual Studio 2010 too btw... ^^

Comment: Dunno no problem here. However, if I enable advanced GPU accel in Photoshop, I get some BSOD with the old driver. The new 256.xx is OK and I got a new card also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Status:** Worked

**Comment:**
We disabled the hardware acceleration in Windows 7. No more problems, Thank you for your comments. Oskar Duveborn and Shiki.

**Additional solutions:**
If for some reason the above does not help you.
There are a lot of options to try.
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404898.html

**P.S.** Thanks for moving my post: Dennis Williamson

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem after reinstalling premiere on a system that had been running perfectly for months.
     *System: ASUS P5KPL-AM EPU / Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 / NVIDIA GeForce GT 240 / 4GB DDR2*

I tried reinstalling a clean win 7 64bit, Premiere + Nvidia drivers again from scratch but same problem.

I found a simple solution that may help others:

**If you have an integrated graphics motherboard the system allocated memory (mine was set at 8MB) it might be clashing with the Nvidia card's faster memory and causing a Open GL conflict.
I opened up the BIOS and set shared integrated memory to 0MB and after the restart everything worked great!**

Hope this helps

e:-)

Answer (score 0):

When I run Photoshop CS5, the following situation will happen.

The NVIDIA OpenGL driver detected a problem with the display
driver and is unable to continue. The application must close.
Error code: 3
Visit [the support page](http://www.nvidia.com/page/support.html) for more information.

My way of solving the problem is:

1. You may uninstall NVIDIA driver at present and restart your system.
2. After then, Win7 will be searching NVIDIA driver online and installing.
3. Downloading the new driver from NVIDIA website.
4. When installing new driver, choosing item 'custom install'.
5. Next choosing item 'remove present driver'
6. After installing, then restart your system.

Comment: When doing a clean install, NVIDIA drives install automatically, but the publisher is Microsoft Corporation. Make sure you download the latest driver from NVIDIA's website.